# Substitutions inside literals in Asciidoc

Tags: asciidoc

There doesn't appear to be a way to have variables (attributes, substitutions) parsed within literal text in Asciidoc, or else I'm missing something. I want to be able to set a variable and then call it inside a code block or literal string as such:

```
:version: 1.0.1
[code]
----
tar -xzvf mysoftware-{version}.tar.gz
----
```

And have it parse to:

```
tar -xzvf mysoftware-1.0.1.tar.gz
```

This can't be impossible, right?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can enable it for any block by using the `subs` attribute to the block. The `subs` attribute accepts any of the following (in a list):

- `none` - Disables substitutions
- `normal` - Performs all substitutions except for callouts
- `verbatim` - Replaces special characters and processes callouts
- `specialchars / specialcharacters` - Replaces <, >, and & with their corresponding entities
- `quotes` - Applies text formatting
- `attributes` - Replaces attribute references
- `replacements` - Substitutes textual and character reference replacements
- `macros` - Processes macros
- `post_replacements` - Replaces the line break character (+)

More info can be found [in the User Manual](http://asciidoctor.org/docs/user-manual/#applying-substitutions), including an example very close to what you're trying to accomplish.

Answer (score 6):

Substitutions inside listing blocks are off by default, but can be controlled with the `subs` parameter:

```
:version: 1.0.1
[code, subs="attributes"]
----
tar -xzvf mysoftware-{version}.tar.gz
----
```

Comment: LightGuard's answer is more complete, but I think it's useful to see how it applies to the example from the question.